# Much or Many for Money?

Tags: grammar, nouns

I was taught that "much" was used for the uncountable nouns and "many" was used for the countable ones. So, why do people often use phrases such as "too much money" or "so much money"?

Are these phrases grammatically correct?

Comment: Suggested transfer to English Learners Stack Exchange.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if saying "one X", "two Xes", etc. sounds right, then you use 'many'.  If not, then you use 'much'.  Nobody says "I have one money" or "I have two moneys", so you don't use 'many' with it.

Comment: Yes, they are correct.

Money, perhaps ironically, is an uncountable noun. In that sense it is grammatically like rice or flour or time and used with a singular verb and with 'much' or 'little' (rather than 'many' or 'a few').

Comment: Note that it's not true that money is always uncountable. It has a plural form: either *monies* or (less commonly) *moneys*. It's possible to talk about *different monies* (and, hence, *many different monies*). This is used in the sense of *currencies*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those phrases are correct. As to why, you have basically answered your own question: *money* is normally an uncountable noun.

*Cambridge Learner's Dictionary* includes annotations [C] and [U] signifying whether a noun is countable or uncountable in a particular meaning. For example, the entry for *money* [(here)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/money) has the annotation [U], while the entry for *table*  [(here)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/table_1) has annotation [C]. And *chicken* has [C] for one meaning ('a bird kept on a farm for its meat and eggs'), but [U] for another ('the meat of a chicken') [(here)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/chicken).